# Why $\mathbb{E}[e^Z]$ is discontinuous and nondifferentiable at $Z$ unless $L_p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is finite dimensional?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading Shapiro's Lecture on Stochastic Programming book. In Example 6.20, he states that
$\mathbb{E}[e^Z]$ is discontinuous and nondifferentiable at $Z$, where $Z \in L_p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P), p\in[1,\infty)$, unless $L_p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is finite dimensional. Here $L_p$ is the normal $L_p$ space with $p$-norm. I only have knowledge on finite dimensional analysis, and I could not figure out why the continuity and differentiability fail in the infinite dimensional case. Can any one gives me some hints or references?

Comment: Let $f(Z) = E(e^{Z})$. Obviously, $f(Z) = \infty$ in some cases and is not well defined on all of $L_p$ except in very special situations, so before doing anything you need to specify a domain for $f$. But formally, $Df(Z)V = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0}E(e^{Z + tV}) = E(e^{Z}V)$. Hence we may expect $\nabla f(Z) = e^{Z} = f(Z)$.

Comment: Could you explain why $f(Z)=\infty$ in some case? Since $Z\in L_p$, it should be in $L_1$ as well, then $E(Z)$ should be finite, so as $E(e^Z)$.

Comment: Example $$\int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x}}}\,{\rm d}x=2\\\int_{0}^{1}\!{{\rm e}^{{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x}}}}}\,{\rm d}x=\infty$$

Comment: Thank you! The example is inspiring. But I'm still wondering, the author said that if $L_p$ is finite dimensional, then $E(e^Z)$ is continuous. It seems that your example gives a contradiction...

Answer (score 0):

The functional needs to be defined on a suitable linear space over which it is always finite; the smallest is $L_\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and the largest is called the *primal entropic space* (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11579-017-0197-9) for definition, its dual and bidual spaces, and its relations to $L_p$ spaces).

In this case, it is continuous and differentiable. The Fréchet derivate of $f(Z) = \mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]$, is given by

$$\nabla f(Z) = e^{Z}.$$

Indeed, the directional derivative $f'_D(Z)$ for direction $D$ is linear in $D$ as follows:

$$f'_D(Z) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(Z+tD)-f(Z)}{t}=\mathbb{E} \left(De^{Z}\right)=\left < \nabla f(Z),D  \right>.$$